# Filter URL's with PHP PCRE

Tags: php, regex, url, pcre

I have a website with, let's say 2000 pages. Some of them are for products and others are for categories. The URL's are like this: for products  `https://www.website.com/product-brand-name-p254.html`  and for categories  `https://www.website.com/category-name-c44.html` . How can I filter the URL's so that in the end I can obtain only the URL's for categories. I made this pcre

```
/https:\/\/w{3}.website.com\/[a-z]*-[a-z]*-[c]{1}[0-9]*.html/g
```

It seems that it works and finds only the URL's for categories. I know that I should use  `preg_match_all();` to check them all but my question is this: How can I get all the URL's names so that I can check them with this function, or is it possible to do that? Thank you!

Comment: How does this regex `[a-z]-[a-z]` match `category-name` part?

Comment: `How can I get all the URL's names` we who shall ask you that, what's your data source?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "get all the URL's names". If you're talking about capturing the category name, put that part of the expression in parentheses. That part will be returned as a separate array.

Comment: Hey revo! each [a-z] has a star after the square bracket.

Comment: Hi alanlittle! Let's say that I have all those files inside a folder but they are mixed and I want to get only the files for categories and move them to another folder. Or at least count them and know how many I have for categories.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what your question is. You say your expression works to extract only the category file names -- what else are you trying to do? What is your expression not doing that you want it to?

Comment: My question alanlittle is, how can I get all the names for all the files so I can check them? How can I put all the 2000 or 10000 files names into a string so I can check them with that function?

Comment: Have you tried actually using the [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function? It returns the matches in an array, which you can then loop over, and do whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem. I had to find out about some functions I din't know. The code, is down below:

```
$location = 'dir';
$files = scandir($location);
$files = array_diff(scandir($location), array('.', '..'));
$matches = preg_grep('/pattern/', $files);
$results = implode("<br>", $matches);
echo $results;
```

I will try to put this into a function.